# How to remove colored text in Microsoft Word document via VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

How to remove colored text in *Microsoft Word* via [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim oWord As Word.Application 
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document 
    Dim oRng As Word.Range 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    oWord = New Word.Application 
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\file.docx") 
    oWord.Visible = True 
    oRng = oDoc.Content 
    If oRng.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack Then 
        oRng.Delete() 
    End If 
    oWord.Documents.Item(1).Save() 
    oWord.Quit() 
    oWord = Nothing 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: ***and... What have you tried?***

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        oWord = New Word.Application
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\file.docx")
        oWord.Visible = True
        oRng = oDoc.Content
        If oRng.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack Then
            oRng.Delete()
        End If
        oWord.Documents.Item(1).Save()
        oWord.Quit()
        oWord = Nothing End Sub End Class

Comment: [Edit] your post and add the code you tried along with a specific problem or question and maybe tit will get reopened.  Study [ask] and maybe visit the [help] for tips on asking a good question